# Prove than an arbitrary group G with the following metric can be realised as a subgroup of Isom(G)

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

Let G be a group with generating set S. I have proved that the following is a metric for G:

$d(g_1,g_2)$=shortest number of edges in a path connecting $g_1$ to $g_2$ in the Cayley Graph of G with generating set S.

I have also proved that this is the same as saying $d(g_1,g_2)=n$, where n is the smallest non-negative integer s.t. $g_2=g_1s_1^{e_1}...s_n^{e_n}$
($s_i∈S$ and $e_i=-1$ or $1$, indicating path of travel along graph edge.

Now, letting Isom(G) be the group of isometries of G with this metric, I am asked to prove that G can be realised as a subgroup of Isom(G).

I take this to mean that I need to find a subgroup of Isom(G) that is isomorphic to G. I think that the isomorphism might be something like:
Send the element g1 to the isomorphism that holds g1 constant and swaps around other elements, but I'm not definite as to how this would work and if so how I would formalise it.

Does anybody have any ideas/tips?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the natural action of $G$ on itself ?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the Cayley graph is set up so that $(g_1,g_2,s_i^{e})$ is an edge from $g_1$ to $g_2$ labeled $s_i^{e}$ means g $g_2=g_1s_i^{e}$, the group acts on the Cayley graph, for $h\in G$, by $h.g=hg$ and $h.(g_1,g_2)=(hg_1,hg_2)$ (since $hg_2=hg_1s_i^{e}$).

If you can show $d(hg_1,hg_2)=d(g_1,g_2)$, then this gives a homomorphism $G\to\operatorname{Isom}(G)$.

Injectivity follows from the fact that $h.e=h$.