# Proper subgroup of own isometry group

Tags: group-theory, isometry

If $G$ is a group and $S$ is a generating set for it, then we can define a distance metric based upon the minimum $S$ operations needed to move from one element of $G$ to another. As a result, $G$ can be shown to be a subgroup of Isom$(G)$. ([Prove than an arbitrary group G with the following metric can be realised as a subgroup of Isom(G)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476490/prove-than-an-arbitrary-group-g-with-the-following-metric-can-be-realised-as-a-s) shows this).

However, every example I can see has $G$ isomorphic to Isom$(G)$. Is there an example where $G$ is a strict subgroup of Isom$(G)$?

Comment: Let $G = \Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z} =\Bbb{Z}_3$ and $S = [1]$, then $G$ has an isometry that corresponds to multiplication by $-1$ when we view $\Bbb{Z}_3$ as a ring.